# Wiredep won't insert bower CSS dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, wiredep

I'm trying to use `wiredep` to inject bower dependencies. I am confused a little about how it works, and why it is only working for my JS files.

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function(cb){
  gulp.src('./index.html')
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

What does the final line `gulp.dest('.')` do? wouldn't the destination be my index.html file. Also, this task only seems to inject javascript files. I have in my bower.json dependencies for

```
"bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
"bourbon": "~4.2.6",
"jquery": "~2.1.4",
"neat": "~1.7.2"
```

Bootstrap, Bourbon, and neat, all have large amounts of CSS, yet the

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
```

remain empty after running `gulp wiredep`. Why would this be?

bower.json deps look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.8",
    "bitters": "~1.1.0",
    "bourbon": "~4.2.6",
    "font-awesome": "fontawesome#~4.5.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "neat": "~1.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all add the official workaround from the bootstrap blog to your project's `bower.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
...
},
"overrides": {
  "bootstrap": {
    "main": [
      "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
      "less/bootstrap.less"
        ]
    }
}
```

For other packages the pattern would be the same but change the path.

Comment: That update needs to be made in _each_ individual package's `bower_components` file? Is there some way to make this process less manual? This seems pretty time-consuming and at-odds with the time-saving intent of this gulp task.. `:/`

Comment: No add it to your project's `bower.json` file. I will add it as an update to the answer.

Comment: Right, i see i missed that the first time. But it does need to be done for ever bower dependency?

Comment: Every bower component that wiredep does not add it by default.

Comment: What would wiredep add by default? Also, can you show me what it would look like for just one of the other dependencies? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: in one of my projects, I wanted to use OnsenUI package and I used the following code snippet in `bower.json` file for wiredep to add the files correctly.
`"overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "less/bootstrap.less"
      ]
    },
    "OnsenUI": {
      "main": [
        "js/onsenui.js",
        "css/*.css"
      ]
    }
  }`